# Url.Action() with area returns empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using Razor in MVC 4. I'm trying to make a URL from a view in an area to a controller action in another area. The following returns an empty string:

```
    @Url.Action("Action", "MyController", new { area = "OtherArea" })
```

I've done some testing with other options, and the following returns a URL, but it's wrong:

```
    @Url.Action("Action", "MyController", new { parameter = 1 })
```

The resulting URL is /App/IncorrectArea/My/Action?parameter=1. Note the incorrect area; Url.Action is assuming (since I didn't pass an area) that the controller lives in the current area which it does not!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Found my issue. I had changed the area name, but failed to update the AreaName property in the Area Registration.

Comment: Have a look at [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) to fix many issues related to strings in MVC.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because I changed the `RegisterRoutes` method from `{controller}/{action}/{id}` to `{action}/{id}` just to emit controller name from URL